# Преобразование двух чисел в одно двухзначное

Tags: python

Есть цикл For который перебирает строку, пример: a32b2e13 и т.д, когда for проходит по символу с цифрой мне нужно что бы его записывало в переменную, это я реализовал а вот как сделать что бы получилось из 3 и 2 - 32 я не знаю...

Comment: А не проще одним регэкспом удалить все не-цифры?

Comment: Дело в том что мне надо потом умножить букву на это число

Comment: Вы полностью задачу изложите, чтобы было понятно, что вам нужно в конечном итоге. Ну и свой код привести было бы не плохо.

Comment: `предыдущая_цифра = предыдущая_цифра * основание_сисемы_счисления + текущая_цифра`

Comment: Это типа "декомпрессия данных", что ли? тогда поделите регэкспом `(одна буква, одна и более цифр)` в массив, причём жадно, а потом "умножайте" первый символ каждого элемента на "хвост", преобразованный в число.

Comment: Нужно что бы выводилось буква столько раз сколько показывает следующая цифра: a2d3 = aaddd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = 'a32b2e13'
count = 0
symbol = ''
result = ''

for ch in data:
    try:
        count = count * 10 + int(ch)
    except ValueError:
        result += symbol * count
        symbol = ch
        count = 0

result += symbol * count

print(result)  # aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае я бы посоветовал воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

a = 'a32b2e13'

elems = re.findall('\D|\d+',a)
res = [elems[x]*int(elems[x+1]) for x in range(0,len(elems),2)]
# результат
print(res)
```

> ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bb', 'eeeeeeeeeeeee']

Comment: Мне кажется с такой регуляркой `re.findall('(\D)(\d+)',a)` цикл станет немного проще выглядеть :)

Comment: @gil9red с такой регуляркой мой код вообще работать не будет, потому как на входе у него будет список кортежей :)

Comment: Когда я написал, про цикл, то и подразумевал что тот поменяется :) `res = [a * int(b) for a, b in re.findall('(\D)(\d+)',a)]`